# Исходники sscli

Tags: c#, .net

Всем доброго вечера! Где можно посмотреть исходники sscli? Все ссылки в старых статьях , наподобие [этой](http://msdn.microsoft.com/net/sscli) переадресуют на главную страницу Майкрософт. Находил [это](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr), но мне кажется, это относится к .net core? Или всё-таки к обычному .net?

Comment: что тут имеется ввиду под `sscli`?

Comment: Shared source cli

Answer (score 1):

Старые SSCLI можно найти на [неофициальном сайте](https://github.com/SSCLI). [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) — это современная кросс-платформенная реализация CLR с открытым кодом, заменившая SSCLI. Исходные коды последних версий классического .NET Framework можно найти на сайте [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: разве net core включает в себя и исходники .net? Я имею в виду устройство виртуальной машины .net. По ссылке referencesource просто исходники based class library. Там нет основных исходников самой виртуальной машины .net, и нет исходников jit-компилятора

Comment: @Александр Для CoreCLR исходные коды виртуальной машины находятся в папке [src/vm](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/vm), а JIT-компилятора — в папке [src/jit](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/jit).  Что касается классического .NET Framework, устанавливающегося в Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64], то исходные коды его VM и JIT не являются открытыми, но они довольно близки к коду CoreCLR. Фактически, CoreCLR унаследовал VM и RyuJIT из классического .NET Framework и продолжил их развивать.